# Undefined youtube api functions

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I am trying to make a percentage bar by doing `player.getCurrentTime(); / player.getDuration(); * 100`

According to [google](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Retrieving_video_information) `player.getCurrentTime()` and `player.getDuration()` should Return the elapsed time in seconds?

I am wanting to then print the percentage into a variable `var percentage =` But I keep getting an undefined error?

Answer (score 2):

You're not using semi-colons correctly, you have them in all the wrong places. They *terminate a statement*, but you're using them as though they have something to do "terminating" function invocation. The code you've posted will be giving you a **syntax** error, as your syntax is fundamentally broken, *not* an "undefined error".

This:

```
player.getCurrentTime(); / player.getDuration(); * 100
```

Needs to be this:

```
player.getCurrentTime() / player.getDuration() * 100;
```

Comment: it is still saying undefined

Comment: @user2768038 Then you're doing something else wrong, but based on the code you've posted, we can't help you. Do some debugging, is `player` even defined?